# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes' trying buildozer android debug

Tags: python, android

I have setup WSL on my Windows 10 machine. I am trying to

```
buildozer android debug
```

on the ubunutu VM started on my Windows 10 machine so that I can convert my python application(s) to android apk(s) as documented in numerous articles. However I am getting stuck at

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

inspite of trying numerous options like

1. install libffi-dev and then reinstall python
2. executing ldconfig

etc. as suggested by numerous posts here.

Any ideas?

following are the exact steps that I had to do for item 1 above (due to numerous errors I used to get trying them) as a reference in case that holds the key:

- sudo apt remove python3
- sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
- sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
- sudo apt-get install python3-apt
- sudo apt-get install python3 (did nothing)

Here is the complete stack of the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main                                                      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,                                                                            File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code                                                                 exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                               File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1312, in                                                                                                                main()                                                                                                                File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main                                                                                                                   ToolchainCL()                                                                                                         File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 734, in **init**                                                                                                                getattr(self, command)(args)                                                                                          File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func                                                                                                            build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)                                                                                 File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args                                                                                                    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,                                                                       File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 504, in build_recipes                                                                                                               recipe.build_arch(arch)                                                                                               File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 934, in build_arch                                                                                                                 self.install_python_package(arch)                                                                                     File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 950, in install_python_package                                                                                                     shprint(hostpython, 'setup.py', 'install', '-O2',                                                                     File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint                                                                                                                    for line in output:                                                                                                   File "/home/sameer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next                                           self.wait()                                                                                                           File "/home/sameer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait                                           self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)                                                                              File "/home/sameer/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code                       raise exc                                                                                                           sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                             RAN: /home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 setup.py install -O2 --root=/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/paadas/armeabi-v7a --install-lib=.                                                                                                                                                               STDOUT:                                                                                                               Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setup.py", line 7, in                                                         import setuptools                                                                                                     File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/**init**.py", line 18, in                                            from setuptools.dist import Distribution                                                                              File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 32, in                                                from setuptools import windows_support                                                                                File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/setuptools/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in                                      import ctypes                                                                                                         File "/home/sameer/paadas/app/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/**init**.py", line 8, in                                                              from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array                                                                         ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Comment: Steps are mentioned - https://bugs.python.org/issue31652.

This has been resolved - https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1183